# Resampling 2 time series

Tags: python, pandas, merge, time-series, data-analysis

I have 2 time series which each have a record every 30 seconds with a difference of about 21 seconds
;

> ts1 starts at 12:30:00
> And the second record at 12:30:30

> ts2 starts at 12:30:21
> And the second record at 12:30:51

What is the best way to merge them without losing information I want to have the same index for both

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC use [`merge_asof`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.merge_asof.html):

```
df = pd.merge_asof(ser1.to_frame('a'), 
                   ser2.to_frame('b'), 
                   left_index=True, 
                   right_index=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have two separate columns for `ts1` and `ts2`, use `pd.concat()` which with a default 'outer' join method, and resample with `ffill()`, if necessary.